# Options for Backing up my VPS

Tags: backup

Hi I would like to setup automatic monthly backups of the files and databases on my VPS, I would like the files to be backed up to another server via FTP and to my home computer with Win 7. I have webmin installed as well on my VPS, if that helps in facilitating setting up the backup. What are my options? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the script from http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-backup-mysql-databases-web-server-files-to-a-ftp-server-automatically.html if your setup is not complex.

Otherwise you can try using [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) which should be able to send the backed up data to your home machine via FTP.

Personally because I back up to a Linux box, I'm using rsnapshot on the client end with a rsync (post-backup script) to transfer the data.